# Node.JS Pyshell crashes on second message to Python, [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Tags: python, node.js

I have a Node.JS server that sends messages to a Python script using Pyshell.send

When Pyshell returns a message using print Node.JS recieves it using pyshell.on and then reads out the returned message.

When this is then done again with a second message it crashes with the error:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:243:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
    at PythonShell.send (/Users/maxkenney/Desktop/nodeLanguageProcessing/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:285:20)
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (/Users/maxkenney/Desktop/nodeLanguageProcessing/app.js:87:10)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Namespace.emit (/Users/maxkenney/Desktop/nodeLanguageProcessing/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:213:10)
    at /Users/maxkenney/Desktop/nodeLanguageProcessing/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:181:14
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:245:10)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I believe it could possibly be because the Python shell is closed after one message but I am unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Node.JS Script (relevant parts)

```
let pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');



pyshell.on('message', function(message){
    console.log("python said: " + message);
});

pyshell.send("This is a test entry").end(function(err){
        if(err) handleError(err);
});
```

That last pyshell.send is repeated later on and it crashes.

Python Script:

```
import sys
import spacy
import nltk

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm");

def convertGeneratorObjectToListOfString(generatorObject):
    list = []

    for item in generatorObject:
        list.append(str(item))

    return list

def main():


    #doc = nlp(sys.argv[1])
    doc = nlp(sys.stdin.readline())

    # Return the printed message to Node
    jsonObjectToReturn = {}

    for token in doc:
        dependents = token.children
        listOfChildrenTag = []

        for d in dependents:
            listOfChildrenTag.append(d.dep_)
        jsonObjectToReturn[token.text] = {
            "text": token.text,
            "lemma": token.lemma_,
            "tag": token.tag_,
            "dep": token.dep_,
            "dependencies": convertGeneratorObjectToListOfString(token.children),
            "dependenciesTag": listOfChildrenTag
        }

    print(jsonObjectToReturn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have included all python code here as I am unsure but I believe the issue could also be caused by the fact that the Python script closes once the main finishes. Apologies I am unfamiliar with running constant python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.end()` you close the stream so it cannot be used any more. So, don't call `.end()` until you're done with the stream.   You can call `.send()` without calling `.end()`.

if you also need to monitor when the python script ends, you can use the `childProcess` property of the pyshell object.

```
let pyshell = new PythonShell('my_script.py');
pyshell.childProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`python program ended with exit code: ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Wow I am really embarrassed that was there, in hindsight I should have spotted that, thanks.

However, I made the changes as you suggested and the error still occurs so I can only imagine something else  is also closing the stream

Comment: @MaxKenney - Has your python script just ended on its own?  You can monitor when it exits from your node.js program and compare the timing of that versus when you get your error.

Comment: I have done a google but I cant seem to find anything on monitoring when the python script ends. Is this built into pyshell? Sorry I am new to a lot of this

Comment: @MaxKenney - See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: 'Python program ended with exit code; 0' after the data is sent